# Typescript union type to single mapped type

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to convert a union type to a map with the key being "type" property?
**e.g. Given a union type Actions:**

```
type Actions =
  | {
      type: 'campaignCreated';
      code: string;
    }
  | {
      type: 'campaignEnded';
      amount: number;
    };
```

**I'd like to be able to receive;**

```
type ActionMap = {
  campaignCreated: {
    type: 'campaignCreated';
    code: string;
  };
  campaignEnded: {
    type: 'campaignEnded';
    amount: number;
  };
};
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it's possible.

We start with  a type for selecting a single union member based on the `type` type:

```
type ActionSelector<T extends Actions['type'], U extends {type: Actions['type']}> = 
    U extends {type: T} ? U : never;
```

It works because conditional types [distribute](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#distributive-conditional-types) the condition over the members of the union type, when the condition argument is a union.

Just a check that it works as expected:

```
type A1 = ActionSelector<'campaignCreated', Actions>
```

Then we can use it as 'value type' in a mapped type:

```
type ActionMap = {[t in Actions['type']]: ActionSelector<t, Actions>};
```

the result is

```
type ActionMap = {
    campaignCreated: {
        type: "campaignCreated";
        code: string;
    };
    campaignEnded: {
        type: "campaignEnded";
        amount: number;
    };
}
```