# In Typescript, how do I map a Union type into a { UnionMemberProp1: OptionalUnionMemberProp2 } type?

Tags: typescript

I've looked at [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51691235/typescript-map-union-type-to-another-union-type) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56981568/61624) that appear to be asking a simplified version of my question, but I can't figure out how to apply them to my specific question. [The following code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiDKwBOBXAxsAKq6BeKA3gFBRQBmKwKSEA+gNYQgBcUAzsgJYB2A5gNwlylanQBuAQwA2KCK2SzBAX0FFQkWAgUYAYtLYgo+YqQpUaDJqw5IeAoWdG1JMiAH5WZfRGWr10OERUDCNNIPQsHCgAHzDtYD0pA1U0AHtuDigAWy1g4ABBJCQJQ3wAbSECYXM6RhYoAHIFCABGBoAaaqcXWXkopXbKros61gavJNaO4fFpXvJvKAGhxxGrRom2CAAmadXZ11YUbgATCDIeCBOlwdIq-ct68e8AZgabogBdKAk2KDSMsB2BJgJw2BcIH8aBITukpIZAvEyp8-OAArkIgBVbicdKhAAU-lSZGyGIwhWKIAAlGVuCgsgAjCBIFFEIgAenZUAAklAAO4SbhA4CpKAMlCcKTXCRQfxQYnMNmc2VoqAAaSYADU5pDQsRlaQmjg2mMQJCOhyuYbNlNWHTGczBgaNt5dnb6UykE6rS7Jm93Q6vZalmy5RqQNrXH9jEJlQA9NxCMpqqA8OJ5bG47g-P6IjM49JlcYiNYgBqfT6sFMQAAewAgpz+JlIM2cOr6iiESiEpDcjTNbAaPagAc9viAA) shows what I'm trying to achieve:

```
type MyStructTrue = {
  future_key: string;
  future_value: true;
};

type MyStructFalsy = {
  future_key: string;
  future_value?: false;
};

type MyStruct = MyStructTrue | MyStructFalsy;

const myStructArray = [
  { future_key: 'true1', future_value: true },
  { future_key: 'false1', future_value: false },
  { future_key: 'false2', future_value: undefined },
  { future_key: 'false3' },
] as const satisfies readonly MyStruct[];

type MyStructUnion = (typeof myStructArray)[number];

// I want to build a type of:

// type KeyValues = {
//   'true1': 'yes',
//   'false1': number,
//   'false2': number,
//   'false3': number,
// }

type KeyValues = {
  // ^?
  [K in MyStructUnion as MyStructUnion['future_key']]: K extends {
    future_value: true;
  }
    ? 'yes'
    : number;
};
```

To me it appears that `K extends { future_value: true; } ? ...`  is applied to all possibilities of `MyStructUnion` instead of individual members. As a result, every value of `KeyValues` is `'yes' | number`.  But I want it to apply that conditional to specific union members to get the type I describe in my code's comment.

I think part of the solution is to use a [Distributive Conditional Type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types), but the type signature of `MyStructFalsy` seems to interfere: `future_value` may not exist as a property so I am unable to access it in a conditional. I haven't figured out a way to wrap anything in `Required<...>` to prevent this.

How do I achieve the `KeyValues` type signature in my comment?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wOl0RN) work for you? If yes, I will write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @wonderflame that looks like it works to me but I haven't completely read it yet, only the type of `Result`. My gut tells me it's what I'm looking for

Comment: Let me know if anything is missing, otherwise, I will write up the answer.

Comment: @wonderflame It looks good to me. Go ahead, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you mentioned in the description, the condition is applied to all possibilities, not to a single member of a union. To fix we should distribute the union, which is possible when we check `K extends K`. Alternatively you could use `K extends any` or `K extends unknown`.

If this condition is true, the following code will be executed for each member of the union separately:

```
{
   [P in K["future_key"]]: true extends K["future_value" & keyof K]
      ? "yes"
      : number;
}
```

Since, `"future_value"` doesn't exist in all members of the union, the `K` isn't inferred to have it as a key. By writing `"future_value" & keyof K` I'm telling Typescript to take the intersection of these two, and if there is no `"future_value"` in `keyof K` the intersection will result in `never`, which will result in `K[never]`, which will result in `never`. Otherwise, the intersection will be `"future_value"` itself.

If we now write `type Result = KeyValues` we will get the following type:

```
{
    true1: "yes";
} | {
    false1: number;
} | {
    false2: number;
} | {
    false3: number;
}
```

This type is the expected behavior; however, we need an intersection for your expected result, not a union. We can use the type mentioned in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375286/21637817).
New version:

```
type KeyValues<K extends MyStructUnion = MyStructUnion> = UnionToIntersection<
  K extends K
    ? {
        [P in K["future_key"]]: true extends K["future_value" & keyof K] ? "yes" : number;
      }
    : never
>;
```

Now `type Result = KeyValues` will result:

```
{
    true1: "yes";
} & {
    false1: number;
} & {
    false2: number;
} & {
    false3: number;
}
```

This is the desired result, however, it doesn't look pretty; that's why we will wrap the whole `KeyValues` type with the following type that makes the intersections disappear by redefining the object:

```
type Prettify<T> = T extends infer R ? {[K in keyof R]: R[K]} : never;
```

Final code:

```
type KeyValues<K extends MyStructUnion = MyStructUnion> = Prettify<
  UnionToIntersection<
    K extends K
      ? {
          [P in K["future_key"]]: true extends K["future_value" & keyof K]
            ? "yes"
            : number;
        }
      : never
  >
>;
```

```
/*
type Result = {
    true1: "yes";
    false1: number;
    false2: number;
    false3: number;
}
*/
type Result = KeyValues;
```

[playground](https://tsplay.dev/wOl0RN)

Comment: I'm confused by that first paragraph and your first example. I think it might be easier if you used `K` to represent the same concept as my `K`, or gave your generic parameters different names. Regardless, I think you are describing Distributive Conditional Types as a "for loop"? Am I understanding that part correctly?

Comment: "If this condition is true the following code will be executed for each union separately. If that condition is true, we will just do the same mapping as you did but changed to the way that I decided to go with, however, it does the same thing as yours." Did you mean for these to both say "true"? Did you mean to say "for each union separately" or "for each union member separately"?

Comment: "I think you are describing Distributive Conditional Types as a "for loop"? Am I understanding that part correctly? " Yes, you are completely right

Comment: `Did you mean to say "for each union separately" or "for each union member separately"?`. Thanks for correcting, yes I meant for each member of union

Comment: What is `& keyof K` doing in your first example? Why do you need that? Is it a way to protect from typos?  "This type is the expected behavior, however, we need an intersection, not a union." Why?

Comment: `This type is the expected behavior, however, we need an intersection, not a union." Why?` 
Do you mean why we need an intersection? We need it because your expected result is the object with all possibilities not a union of possibility. If you are asking why a union  is the expected behavior it's because we distributed the `K` and the we will get a union of possibilities

Comment: "Do you mean why we need an intersection?" Yeah, that's what I meant, thanks. "We need it because your expected result is the object with all possibilities not a union of possibility." Oh, that makes sense to me. Thank you. re: your previous comment, `By writing "future_value" & keyof K I'm telling ts to take the intersection of these two ... never`. Will it become `K[never]`? What will happen next in the evaluation?

Comment: " Will it become `K[never]`? What will happen next in the evaluation?" Yes, it will be `K[never]` which will be evaluated as `never`

Comment: What happens after it is evaluated to `never`? `true extends never ? ...` returns the false branch, so it becomes `number`? Wouldn't you want `'yes'` instead; you said, "there is "future_value" in keyof K the intersection will result never".

Comment: Imagine the `&` as the intersection of two sets. First set `['future_value']` and the other `['future_key']`. Their intersection is empty set `[]` a.k.a `never` in our case. However, if the first set is `['future_value']` and the second is `['future_value', 'future_key']`, the intersection will be just `['future_value']`. Thus, if there is `future_value` in the `keyof K` we will get `"yes"`, if it isn't there we get `number`

Comment: Right... I think I interpreted "there is "future_value" in keyof K the intersection will result never" to mean "it evaluates to `never` if there **is** a "future_value" key`. It sounds like you are saying the opposite though.

Comment: forgot a "no" in that comment. My apologies. Can't update it already

Comment: deleted that comment, check the new one:
since, `"future_value"` doesn't exist in all members of the union, the `K` isn't inferred to have it as a key. By writing `"future_value" & keyof K` I'm telling ts to take the intersection of these two, and if there is no  `"future_value"` in `keyof K` the intersection will result `never`

Comment: Okay thank you. Can you review your original answer and include the information in this conversation? I want to make sure there are no typos in the answer I accept. Thanks again.

Comment: thanks, for noting all of the issues. Updated the answer